# Validate first element in list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-validation

I have viewmodel like this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<string> SubSiteNames { get; set; }
}
```

In view I do this

```
    @for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        <label>Name </label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubSiteNames[i - 1])
    }
```

The problem with validation.I need that  first element will be required.How can I achieve it?

Note:

I want provide Validation.When user click submit,the message "The name is required" is appeared for first textbox

Answer (score 1):

You can write `Custom` `DataAnnotation`  for `List` to **not have** first element `null`

```
public class MustHaveFirstElementAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = value as IList;
        if (list != null)
        {
            return list[0] != null;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

      [MustHaveFirstElementAttribute (ErrorMessage = "First Element is required")]
        public List<YourClass> SubSiteNames{ get; private set; }
```

If u want to do it with jquery

```
 @for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        <label>Name </label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubSiteNames[i - 1],new { id="site"+i.ToString()})
    }
```

Then on submit in jquery

```
    $("#submit").click(function(e){

     if($("site1").val()=="")
       {
         alert("Invalid");
        e.preventDefault();
       }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand you answer.I need that in collection SubSiteNames only first will be required

Comment: then just use FirstOrDefault() or First() and check if its null or not

Comment: I want provide Validation.When user click submit,the message "The name is required" is appered for first textbox

Comment: But I can't use it for client validation

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated to make only the first item in the collection required. I suggest you creating a separate property for that and mark it as required:

> ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string RequiredName { get; set; }
    public List<string> SubSiteNames { get; set; }
}
```

> View

```
<label>Name </label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RequiredName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RequiredName)
@for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    <label>Name </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubSiteNames[i - 1])
}
```

Then just remove the first item from the `SubSiteNames` list and set it to the `RequiredName`.